# How to change the value of the index in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change the value of the index of the for loop inside the loop with an if statement.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
    if i==5:
    i=10
```

The result is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What I am expecting is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Short answer, you can't do that on for..in loop.